# Changed from windows to ubuntu 18.04 - Hdd mount issues

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have changed from windows to ubuntu without formating my drives.
When I try to mount them with "disks" 2 of the drives overwrite the changes on each other. How can I find out why this happens? They are not in raid or have the same name etc.
When doing sudo fdisk -1 I get the following: [sudo fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17zSR.png)

"Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary"

Does this have anything to do with why I cannot mount both at the same time?
EDIT: [sudo blkid cat /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLFa2.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Made the edit, i think  i can see the reason now. Seems to have the same UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: "*drives overwrite the changes on each other*"

Using the `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` commands, we see that /dev/sdc2 and /dev/sdd2 have the same UUID. You obviously cloned these disks, and that's why the mount problem.

Use these commands to reset the UUID on ONE of these partitions...

```
sudo uuidgen -r # generate random UUID

sudo tune2fs -U UUID_from_previous_command /dev/sdd2 # set new UUID
```

You can also use `gparted` to reset UUID's.

re: "*Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary*"

This can only be solved by rebuilding the disks from scratch, and making sure to select the "align to sector boundaries" when creating the partitions.

Comment: This looks good, this will not format the disk?

Comment: @PatientBelt no, it just changes the UUID. If it gives you any trouble, then you might need to unmount the disk first.

Comment: This worked really well! Thanks alot